# Creating a "Flag It" function on articles for revision

Tags: knowledge

Our users create 50+ Knowledge Articles a day. For better moderation we would like for any user to be able to flag an article that has inaccurate information. Best case scenario the flag would put the article in back in draft mode and re-assign the article to the original creator for edit.

I would like the flag to be in-line with "Rate This Article, Edit, etc".

Any help on where to start with this would be greatly appreciated.

[image: The flag would be in the article view page block.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I'm guessing you want a button that, when clicked, would perform DML on the record itself.

You could, for instance use an OnClick JavaScript button to achieve this alongside a global class that could use Apex to process the record however you like.

The button's JS might look something like this:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")} 

sforce.apex.execute('MyClass','MyMethod', {myId:'{!My_Object__c.Id}',myStatus:"Innaccurate"}); 
window.location.reload();
```

This will effectively call the method "MyMethod" in the class "MyClass" and pass through the parameters you'd need to work with followed by reloading it.

Once you've passed through the parameters to Apex, you can really do whatever you like with it. The global class might look something like this

```
global class MyClass {
    public static void MyMethod(String myId, String myStatus ) {
        doMyMethod(new List<String>{ myId }, myStatus );
    }

    private static void doMyMethod(List<String> myId, String myStatus) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but hopefully it gives you some idea on how to tackle the problem as you asked for.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion, I am very close to accomplishing this task using your suggestion. Do you know of any way to get a custom button on the Article View pages(articleOnlineDetail.apex)?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not something I've done before so I couldn't reliably answer. But it'd be worth asking another question! I'm sure someone would know here!